# How to Map a Collection of Child Objects where Destination has property mapped from Parent in Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm attempting to use Automapper to map from ParentSource to Destination:

```
public class ParentSource
    {
        public string ParentProperty { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ChildSource> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildSource
    {
        public string ChildProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination
    {
        // Map from Parent.ParentProperty
        public string ParentProperty { get; set; }
        // Map from Child.ChildProperty
        public string ChildProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

such that the destination has a mapping from both the parent and child.  This would be straight forward if the Child property wasn't a collection.

So a parent object with 2 children

Parent:
| ParentProperty |
| -------------- |
| A              |

Child:

| ChildProperty |
| --- |
| C |
| D |

Maps to

Destination:

| ParentProperty | ChildProperty |
| --- | --- |
| A | C |
| A | D |

I can't fathom if this is even possible using automapper?  Can automapper be used to accomplish this and if so, what would the mapping config be?